# Modify braket package for different brackets forms

Tags: brackets, braket

I really don't know how to properly modify codes. Still, my problem is that I would like to know how to modify the following code from the package [braket](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/braket/braket.sty) (in the link the whole `.sty` file, which is quite small btw, *the code below is more than half of the entire code*) to get it work for all sort of brackets.

Here there is the piece of code from the link I think is relevant here:

```
% \Set{...|...} Only the first | is treated specially.
{\catcode`\|=\active
  \xdef\set{\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname set \endcsname}
  \expandafter\gdef\csname set \endcsname#1{\mathinner
        {\lbrace\,{\mathcode`\|32768\let|\midvert #1}\,\rbrace}}
  \xdef\Set{\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname Set \endcsname}
  \expandafter\gdef\csname Set \endcsname#1{\left\{%
     \ifx\SavedDoubleVert\relax \let\SavedDoubleVert\|\fi
     \:{\let\|\SetDoubleVert
     \mathcode`\|32768\let|\SetVert
     #1}\:\right\}}
}
\def\midvert{\egroup\mid\bgroup}
\def\SetVert{\@ifnextchar|{\|\@gobble}% turn || into \|
    {\egroup\;\mid@vertical\;\bgroup}}
\def\SetDoubleVert{\egroup\;\mid@dblvertical\;\bgroup}

% If the user is using e-TeX with its \middle primitive, use that for
% verticals instead of \vrule.
%
\begingroup
 \edef\@tempa{\meaning\middle}
 \edef\@tempb{\string\middle}
\expandafter \endgroup \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
 \def\mid@vertical{\middle|}
 \def\mid@dblvertical{\middle\SavedDoubleVert}
\else
 \def\mid@vertical{\mskip1mu\vrule\mskip1mu}
 \def\mid@dblvertical{\mskip1mu\vrule\mskip2.5mu\vrule\mskip1mu}
\fi
```

Thus, I would like to know how to modify the code to create new commands (e.g. a command `\Name`) such that I get – say – square brackets, and the delimiter | still adapts in the middle to the size of the brackets.

How to do it?

Any feedback is most welcome!

*PS: Actually, the idea of the original developer was exactly to give the flexibility to all users to modify `braket` in their own way... however I am clearly a not sophisticated enough user. :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on [Emma's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332969/modify-braket-package-for-different-brackets-forms#comment816321_332981/), here is a version of `\Sequence{...|...}` that is similar to `\Set` from the `bracket` package.  I intentionally shortened the code to remove redundancy now that the `\middle` command from `e-TeX` is standard, but I also removed the ability to turn `||` into `\|` because I'm only interested in a single `|` separator.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} 
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{etex, fixltx2e}
\usepackage{braket} %  for the \Set{...|...} command

% want to define \Sequence{...|...} to be similar to \Set of the braket package

{\catcode`\|=\active
  \xdef\Sequence{\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname Sequence \endcsname}
  \expandafter\gdef\csname Sequence \endcsname#1{\left\langle%
     \:{
     \mathcode`\|32768\let|\SetVert
     #1}\:\right\rangle}
}
\def\SetVert{\egroup\;\middle|\;\bgroup}


\begin{document}
\[
\Sequence{ B^{c^f}_d | d < \omega^2 }
\]

\[
\Set{ B^{c^f}_d | d < \omega^2 }
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the `braket` package, but the [`mathtools`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools?lang=en) package provides some nice commands for declaring paired delimiters. In particular, the documentation gives some examples of defining braket-like macros using `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX`.

For example, the documentation gives the following code snippet for what I think you might want (a braket-like set macro):

```
% just to make sure it exists
\providecommand\given{}
% can be useful to refer to this outside \Set
\newcommand\SetSymbol[1][]{%
\nonscript\:#1\vert
\allowbreak
\nonscript\:
\mathopen{}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\Set[1]\{\}{%
\renewcommand\given{\SetSymbol[\delimsize]}
#1
}

\[ \Set*{ x \in X \given \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+1} > 1 } \]
```

(This is actually more complicated than probably needs to be, because it deals with spacing.) Of course there are many ways to use this package to define similar macros.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the answer! Concerning it, I was wondering how to modify it to call – say – the command `\Name`, and how to get the vertical bar by just inserting $|$ (as in braket, which is very handy), instead of writing `\given`.

Comment: Actually, I figured out how to modify the name, but still I cannot find a way to substitute `\given` with the simple symbol `|`. Do you have any idea on how to implement it? Btw, I edited the original question inserting the piece of code from `braket`.

Comment: If you just want to modify the code above from `braket`, it should suffice to replace all instances of `set` and `set` (but _not_ `\SetVert` and `\SetDoubleVert`) with `name` and `Name`, respectively, and replace `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` with the desired left and right brackets.

Comment: To use `|` in place of `\given` in the `mathtools` example I gave, add `\providecommand\given{\vert} \catcode\`\|=\active \def|{\given}` 
to the preamble. 
Note, however, that this will break usage of `||` as shorthand for a double vertical line (also achievable with `\Vert` or `\|`, which will not be broken) throughout the document. It looks like this is fixed in the `braket` code, but I haven't been able to adapt the fix to the `mathtools` setting.

Comment: @Emma If you're replacing `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` (from the `braket` package code) with the desired left and right brackets, also remember that `\{` is a synonym for `\lbrace` and similarly `\}` is a synonym for `\rbrace`, so these also need to be replaced.  For some reason, the (short) `braket` package code uses both versions.

Comment: @Emma: Since you were so helpful in this problem, I just wanted to let you know that I am still struggling with these lines of codes, even if this time the problem is with spacing. Here there is a question I asked concerning this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508906/modify-braket-package-to-control-the-space-between-text-and-brackets?noredirect=1&lq=1